# Where are thrown objects allocated?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

When I use `throw` in a function, for example

```
try {
   // ...
   throw MyExceptionType()
   // ...
} catch(MyExceptionType& exp){ /* ... */ }
```

Where is `MyExceptionType` allocated? Is it on the stack? If so, is it safe to modify `exp` in my `catch` block? What about calling some other functions inside the `catch` and use the stack?

In a similar case I have:

```
try {
   char my_array[32];
   throw my_array; 
} catch(char* error_string){ /* ... */ }
```

Is `error_string` pointing to somewhere in the process stack? Can I run over the array if I call some functions inside `catch` block?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404288/how-are-exceptions-allocated-on-the-stack-caught-beyond-their-scope

Comment: HAL's link has a good explanation.  I wonder how C++11 made the "special place" thread safe.

Comment: @brianbeuning: by telling the compiler makers that it should be :)

Answer (score 2):

It's implementation dependant.  `g++ 4.4` tries to `malloc` the memory and if that fails tries to construct the exception in an system wide emergency buffer, failing all that it calls `std::terminate`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a behaviour that is implementation dependant and is also strictly related to the used ABI .

If you are under linux/unix I suggest to take a look at `libsupc++` from GNU .

In a nutshell it's like any other library, you don't have a standard implementation for every compiler/C++ standard library, but you have to take a look at how the given instruction is implemented by who wrote the library.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to the implementation.  Different implementations have
different policies, but for the most part, they involve some
special pre-allocated space, either static or thread local.  (If
you have to allocate to throw `std::bad_alloc`, you're in
trouble.)

As for your second case, it's not really similar, because array
to pointer conversions occur before the throw.  So you're really
only throwing a pointer; the space for the pointer is handled as
usual, but once you've left the block where the array was
declared, it's gone.  Even in the `catch` block (in your
example), accessing it is undefined behavior.